# How can I get started with SharePoint development?

Tags: 2007, development, training

I am new to SharePoint and I find this product more for document management, workflows, collaboration sort of things and learned the basics concepts of site management.

Now I wanna move on to the development area and prepared my machine with the following.

1. Configured MOSS 2007 (Enterprise)
2. Installed SQLServer 2005 (Standard Edition)
3. Installed Visual Studio 2008
4. Installed Enterprise Library 4.1
5. Installed WSPBuilder from codeplex

Now my background is Web Application developer and developed different database applications for telecom industry and ERP related modules and want a clue that how to develop applications using Visual Studio and ASP.NET target for MOSS (2007) what kinda typical applications I can develop for MOSS and to start with what should I do first I mean my first assignment to get acquainted with the development and see the result on a SharePoint site.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following resources:

- [What technical skills do you use most when developing/deploying SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3191/what-technical-skills-do-you-use-most-when-developing-deploying-sharepoint/3192#3192)
- [SharePoint where to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500179/sharepoint-where-to-start-closed)
- [Getting started developing for SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110341/getting-started-developing-for-sharepoint)
- [Learning Sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953437/learning-sharepoint)
- [SharePoint for a C# ASP.NET Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535255/sharepoint-for-a-c-asp-net-developer)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start with a search like

[best start development](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=best+start+development)