# Basic skills required for Sharepoint

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What technical skills do you use most when developing/deploying SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3191/what-technical-skills-do-you-use-most-when-developing-deploying-sharepoint)
>   [An introduction to SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/an-introduction-to-sharepoint-2010)
>   [Tips for starting SharePoint development](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26954/tips-for-starting-sharepoint-development)

I am web developer having 5 years of experience in the classical ASP , So just I want to upgrade my technology and  skills ,  So  I am planning  do course on Share Point  .
My question is what are the skills required before staring the share point and which is suitable for my profile, Share Point Administrator / Share Point Developed.
Please guide me ….

Prashanth,
bangalore