# What sites or blogs are available that demonstrate the new features of SharePoint 2010?

Tags: learning

I'd like to know more full details about the new SharePoint 2010 features.

Comment: please make this kind of open questions with several answers Community Wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This subject have been up several times already on this site.
Check 
[What resources would you recommend to someone who would like to learn and possibly become a SharePoint Developer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-resources-would-you-recommend-to-someone-who-would-like-to-learn-and-possibl)

[What is something I should to to help me to Learning SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/what-is-something-i-should-to-to-help-me-to-learning-sharepoint)

For developers I usually suggest
http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/SharePoint2010Developer/

For IT pros and architects check out TechNet
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff627858.aspx

Comment: @Anders: Please feel free to use the 'close' feature to mark questions as duplicates, although in this case I don't think anyone has asked this question for 2010 yet. Thanks :-)